# How can I fix spacing to the right of screen

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

So far the in my html file I have a canvas and a div tag. The div tag contains four paragraph tags which I'm trying to set at the top of the screen, in the middle, and inline. The problem arises when I set them inline and try to add some padding to it. The the third paragraph suddenly just drops to under the first paragraph. Heres the css and html right now.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:rgb(33, 96, 33);
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 130%;
    color:azure;
}

p {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color:azure;
    border: 1px solid azure;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<div id="Events">
  <p id="clicks">Clicks:</p>
  <p id="dbClicks">Double Clicks:</p>
  <p id="mouseLeft">Mouse Left:</p>
  <p id="keyPress">Key Presses:</p>
</div>
```

I tried getting rid of all the margin and padding so I did

margin: 0;
padding: 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `<p>` tag `display: inline-block;` and set the container of these four paragraph `width: 100vw;`.

```css
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid azure;
  }

  canvas {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(33, 96, 33);
    border: 1px solid azure;
  }

  div {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 130%;
    color: azure;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  p {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color: azure;
    border: 1px solid azure;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<div id="Events">
  <p id="clicks">Clicks:</p>
  <p id="dbClicks">Double Clicks:</p>
  <p id="mouseLeft">Mouse Left:</p>
  <p id="keyPress">Key Presses:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to set middle all paragraph you can try like below, please comment for more clarity.

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid azure;
}

canvas {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
user-select: none;

border: 1px solid azure;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<div id="Events" style="text-align: center;">
    <p id="clicks">Clicks:</p>
    <p id="dbClicks">Double Clicks:</p>
    <p id="mouseLeft">Mouse Left:</p>
    <p id="keyPress">Key Presses:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/modify this lines to your CSS:

```
canvas {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

and div must be `div { position: relative; [...] }`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to `display:inline-block;` and not `display:inline;`.
Also add a `margin:0;` to `<p>` tags.

Also, if you want to display the `<p>` tags in one line, add `width:100%;` to your `.div`.

Something like this:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:rgb(33, 96, 33);
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 130%;
    color:azure;
}

p {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color:azure;
    border: 1px solid azure;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<div id="Events">
  <p id="clicks">Clicks:</p>
  <p id="dbClicks">Double Clicks:</p>
  <p id="mouseLeft">Mouse Left:</p>
  <p id="keyPress">Key Presses:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is what you want.  What I did was made a container div for your canvas and your `Events` div to be inside.  I then aligned both items to be centered in the container and adjusted the top position of `events`.

See what I did here:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:rgb(33, 96, 33);
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

#Events{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 130%;
    color:azure;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

p {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color:azure;
    border: 1px solid azure;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

#container {
 position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<div id="Events">
  <p id="clicks">Clicks:</p>
  <p id="dbClicks">Double Clicks:</p>
  <p id="mouseLeft">Mouse Left:</p>
  <p id="keyPress">Key Presses:</p>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:  I also am not sure of the nature of this project, but maybe using `div` in place of `p` could make this even smoother. See here:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:rgb(33, 96, 33);
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

#Events{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 130%;
    color:azure;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#Events div{
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color:azure;
    border: 1px solid azure;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%;
    word-wrap: none;
  
}

#container {
 position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<div id="Events">
  <div id="clicks">Clicks:</div>
  <div id="dbClicks">Double Clicks:</div>
  <div id="mouseLeft">Mouse Left:</div>
  <div id="keyPress">Key Presses:</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the div is not taking the complete space. so now it does.

The paragraphs will still move down if you add padding to them, because you know they are inline element not flex

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:rgb(33, 96, 33);
    border: 1px solid azure;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 130%;
    color:azure;
    width:100%;
}

p {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color:azure;
    border: 1px solid azure;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<div id="Events">
  <p id="clicks">Clicks:</p>
  <p id="dbClicks">Double Clicks:</p>
  <p id="mouseLeft">Mouse Left:</p>
  <p id="keyPress">Key Presses:</p>
</div>
```